# Идем и сам все увидишь

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая в данном предложении?
*Идем(,) и сам все увидишь, друг мой.* (Использовано в диалоге.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Идем, и сам все увидишь, друг мой.***

Запятая ставится.

Два односоставных определенно-личных предложения входят в ССП, но форма и значение у них разные.

Первое предложение имеет значение побуждения к совместному действию, а во втором предложении глагол стоит в изъявительном наклонении (в форме будущего времени).

Comment: А если рассматривать обращение как общий элемент?

Comment: Обращение обозначает всего лишь  лицо, к которому обращена речь. Разве оно может соединить два предложения в одну фразу? А если так: "Идем, и ты сам все увидишь, друг мой".  Тоже не поставим запятую?

Comment: Не думаю, что наличие местоимения на что-то влияет. Если вводное слово может соединить, то и обращение вполне. Тогда пауза при чтении должна отсутствовать. Не говорю, что нужно ставить, а что можно, если автор относит обращение к первому глаголу тоже - а это здесь логично.

Comment: Вы очень формально воспринимаете это правило. После обращения могут следовать два распространенных предложения, которые вы никаким образом не прочитаете в одну фразу.

Comment: Возможно, но тут можно. Но то же можно и про вводное слово сказать.

Comment: Про вводное слово такое нельзя сказать, там семантика важна. Если оно относится к обоим предложениям, то и  надо показать, что  онообъединяет их.

Comment: Общий элемент обычно находится в первой части ПП. Но об обращениях как об общих членах  нигде информацию не встречала

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос № 307783
Здравствуйте, уважаемые сотрудники ГРАМОТЫ! Скажите, пожалуйста, ставится ли запятая между частями сложносочинённого предложения при наличии обращения? Можно ли рассматривать обращение как общее для обеих частей и не разделять их запятой? Предложения такие: Сынок, я всегда рядом(,) и всё, что у меня есть,— твоё. / Мамочка, мы очень тебя любим(,) и все твои внуки очень тебя уважают. Спасибо!

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

Обращение не упоминается как компонент, объединяющий две части сложносочиненного предложения, ни в полном академическом справочнике «Правила орфографии и пунктуации» под редакцией В. В. Лопатина, ни в руководствах Д. Э. Розенталя, ни в «Правилах орфографии и пунктуации» 1956 года. Наиболее общий принцип, лежащий в основе правил об «отмене» запятой в сложносочиненном предложении, сформулирован в Правилах 1956 года:

«Запятая перед союзами и, да (в значении «и»), или, либо не ставится, если соединяемые ими предложения имеют общий второстепенный член или общее придаточное предложение. Наличие общего второстепенного члена или общего придаточного предложения тесно связывает такие предложения в одно целое...»

То есть объединяет части какой-то компонент, который является структурным и смысловым элементом обеих частей предложения, или относится к обеим частям. Обращение грамматически не связано с предложением, не является членом предложения. Вероятно, это дает основание авторам руководств по пунктуации не упоминать обращение как компонент, «отменяющий» запятую. При этом и в академическом справочнике, и у Д. Э. Розенталя говорится, что объединяющую функцию может выполнять вводное слово, а оно, как и обращение, не является членом предложения. Однако это кажется вполне соответствующим принципу, прописанному в правиле: вводное слово, указывая на оценку достоверности высказывания, выражая чувства говорящего и т. д., относиться ко всему предложению в целом, объединяет его части.

Может ли такой функцией обладать обращение? Нам кажется, что объединяющий потенциал у обращения есть. «Русская грамматика» пишет:

«Обращение не является таким распространителем, который никак не связан с остальным составом предложения. Такая связь существует. Она выражается, во-первых, в том, что любое предложение, сообщающее о действии или состоянии определенного субъекта и имеющее в качестве сказуемого глагол в форме 2 л., с абсолютной регулярностью может распространяться обращением, называющим субъект, который либо обозначен в подлежащем местоимением, либо не обозначен совсем: Куда так, кумушка, бежишь ты без оглядки? (Крыл.); Ах, раскиньтесь, строчки песнопений, над землею вечно молодой (Прок.); Откройся, мысль! Стань музыкою, слово (Забол.).

<...>

В художественной литературе, в поэзии функции обращения расширяются и обогащаются. Основная, общеязыковая функция адресования речи сохраняется; однако здесь она не только не является единственной, но очень часто оказывается ослабленной или преобразованной».

Здесь же приводится несколько примеров такого расширения функций обращения: «В поэтической речи обращение может вводить основную тему, называть тот предмет, которому посвящено последующее повествование», «сохраняя функцию называния того, к кому адресована речь, обращение в художественной, поэтической речи часто сосредоточивает в себе центральную часть сообщения» и др.

Таким образом, мы видим, что обращение может быть семантически очень значимым компонентом предложения, по смыслу связанным со всем предложением. А значит, оно способно объединять части.

В Ваших предложениях в соответствии с буквой правила запятую ставить нужно, но духу правила отвечает вариант без запятой. Внутри частей есть местоимения, которые указывают на того, кто назван в обращении, то есть связь частей с обращением выражена.

Однако мы нашли предложения (и пока только такие), где при наличии обращения объединения не происходит, например: Сынок, я всю жизнь оберегал Амина, и всю жизнь меня за это били по рукам [О. Гриневский. Восток ― дело тонкое (1998)]

Очевидно, что Ваш вопрос требует научного изучения, а правила ― уточнения.

Answer (score 0):

Запятую можно и не ставить, так как обращение "*друг мой*" является общим для двух глаголов:
*Идем и сам все увидишь, друг мой.* || При этом предложение читается без паузы в одну фразу.

Если автор хочет подчеркнуть следственность действий, то нужна запятая:
*[Сначала] идем, и [потом] сам все увидишь, друг мой.* || Пауза делается, обращение уже не относится к первому элементу.

Без общего элемента запятая ставится, так как глаголы не согласованы:
*Идем, и сам все увидишь.* || Разное лицо глаголов.
*Идешь и сам все видишь.* || Одинаковое лицо глаголов.

Comment: oleedd, обращение не является общим элементом.

Comment: Может являться. Но такое встречается крайне редко. Запрета на это в правилах нет. Как же ещё автору связать обращение с обеими частями?

Comment: Правила не могут охватить все случаи. К тому же в правилах также не говорится, что обращение может выступать общим элементом. Обращение, как верно отметила Sharon,  обозначает всего лишь лицо, к которому обращена речь.

Comment: Вы сами себе ответили: "Правила не могут охватить все случаи." А очень редкие случаи в правилах даже не рассматривают (учёные не могут учесть всё). Не получиться создать справочник, в котором будут рассмотрены все правила и исключения. Часто ответы приходится "искать" самому. Sharon вот в курсе. А как вам это? *Идём, и не забудь закрыть дверь, Серёжа.* Серёжа - тот, кто остаётся.

Comment: При чем тут тот, кто остается? Надо исходить из смысла, а не из формального правила. Запятая в вашем предложении на месте.

Comment: При том, что "идём" обращено к одному человеку, а остальное - к другому. Если всё к одному - то это лучше показать пунктуационно.

Comment: Здесь одно лицо, и именно к нему обрашена речь. От пунктуации значение не меняется. Здесь возможно только поставить запятую. Отсутствие запятой является ошибкой.

Comment: Не является. Если обращение соединяет элементы, совсем меняется интонация при чтении и отсутствует пауза.

Answer (score 0):

**Комментарий к ответу oleedd**

Интересный материал (ответ справочной службы русского языка). Но в любом случае для окончательного решения нужно видеть контекст.

1. Я могу представить ЧАСТНЫЙ СЛУЧАЙ, когда обращение может стать общим элементом.  Тогда это нужно произнести так: ***Идем и сАм все увидишь, дрУг мой.***  В этом случае собеседник в чем-то сомневается, и тогда  подчеркивается связь слов «сам – друг мой». На «идем» ударение не падает, поэтому паузы нет. Но сложно сказать, что прочтение  и понимание будет именно таким. И это очень редкий случай.
2. Вариант с запятой тоже возможен и является основным:  ***ИдЁм, и сАм все увидишь, дрУг мой.*** Настораживает только тот факт, что обращение стоит в конце предложения.  Как-то оно здесь не на месте, но это от стиля зависит. Возможно, персонаж так привык говорить.
3. Вариант редактирования: ***ИдЁм, дрУг мой, и сАм все увидишь.***

**ВЫВОД.** В некоторых случаях для проверки пунктуации контекст особенно необходим.

Comment: В пользу отсутствия запятой максимальная краткость первого предложения. А мне видится вариант без запятой как основной, ударение на "идём" как-то не очень.

Comment: Краткость тут ни при чем, ведь при отсутствии обращения запятая ставится в этом кратком предложении.  А вот если обращение претендует на общий элемент, то для этого должны быть особые причины. И объяснить это можно  только  интонационными средствами, которые всерьез мало кто воспринимает. Так что от такого оформления могут быть только одни неприятности :)

Comment: Да нет, вы же сами говорили, что, чем длиннее предложения, тем хуже они объединяются. Так вот это правда.

Comment: Говорила, не отрицаю, но только не в этом случае.  Здесь  даже короткие предложения  из-за их разной структуры сложно объединить. У меня такое впечатление, что  они отталкиваются друг от друга, как одинаковые заряды в физике.

Comment: А у меня, наоборот, притягиваются :) Но если их расширить, то они ещё хуже будут объединяться.